# How To Resolve `null` Value In Action From ListBox In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Salaamun Alekum

I Am Getting `null` Value In Action From ListBox In MVC

> HR_TP_Supplier    null    Assignment1MedicineMasterPharmacy.Models.HR_TP_Supplier

Here Is CSHTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HR_TP_Supplier, "Supplier", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.ListBox("HR_TP_Supplier", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HR_TP_Supplier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here Is C# Action Code

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MedicineID,Med_Name,Med_code,Generic_Name,Trade_Price,Retail_Price,Accounting_Unit,Nature,THERAPEUTIC_Group,Dosage,Description,Active,Enteredby,Enteredon,ClientID,HR_TP_Supplier")] PH_tmedicine_masterSubmit pH_tmedicine_master)
        {
```

This Is Entity Class

```
namespace Assignment1MedicineMasterPharmacy.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class PH_tmedicine_masterSubmit
    {
        public int MedicineID { get; set; }
        public string Med_Name { get; set; }
        public string Med_code { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Generic_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Trade_Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Retail_Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Accounting_Unit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Nature { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> THERAPEUTIC_Group { get; set; }
        public string Dosage { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public string Enteredby { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Enteredon { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ClientID { get; set; }
        public virtual HR_TP_Supplier HR_TP_Supplier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How Should I Resolve It I Want Multiple Selected Values From ListBox In Anything Like List Or Array Or String

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the entities created by your ORM in your view is not a great idea, especially when your view is a bit more than one or two fields. 
You should create a view model for your view.

The `HR_TP_Supplier`  property on your `PH_tmedicine_masterSubmit` entity is not a collection type. Not sure why you want multi select list box for that. Anyway, If you really want the multi select list box in your view, You can add a property of string array to store the selected item from the Multi select listbox.

```
public class MedicineMasterVm
{      
  public string[] SelectedSuppliers { get; set; }  
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; }    

  //Add Other needed properties here
  public string Med_Name { get; set; }
  public string Med_code { get; set; }
}
```

And in your GET action, you should create an object of this, load the `Suppliers`  property and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new MedicineMasterVm();
    //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you mat replace with DB data.
    vm.Suppliers= new[]
    {
      new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Supplier 1" },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Supplier 2" },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Supplier 3" }
    };  
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your View, Which is strongly typed to `MedicineMasterVm` class,

```
@model UserViewModel
<h2>Create Medicine </h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Name</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Med_Name)
  <label>Code</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Med_Code)
  <label>Suppliers</label> @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedSuppliers ,Model.Suppliers)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now when user posts this form, you will get the Selected Items value in the `SelectedSuppliers`  property of the view model. Read the property values of your posted view model and use that to build your entity object and save.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(MedicineMasterVm model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string[] supplierArray= model.SelectedSuppliers  ;
        //check items now
        //do your further things and follow PRG pattern as needed
    }
    //reload the Suppliers property again in the ViewModel before returning to the View
    return View(model);
}
```

If you want a single select normal dropdown,change the string array to just a string or int and use that as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300916/dropdownlist-from-ienumerable/34301135#34301135).