# Getting the chosen item from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use JavaScript for populating a list called "groups".

Then I create a DropDownList:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("groups", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Choose...")
    </div>
</div>
```

The DropDownList displays fine.

What I need to do is assign the chosen value from "groups" to the model.group_id.
I don't know how to get the item chosen in DropDownList in the controller method. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This is not C#; this is Javascript and Razor and Bootstrap.

Comment: the controller is in c#, I asked about the controller.

Comment: Did you google? Can you use DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a form field in your form with the name `group_id` like this and you want to set the selected value from your dropdown to that field for some reason,

```
@Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.group_id)  
<div class="form-group">       
  @Html.DropDownList("groups",new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Choose...")  
</div>
```

You can listen to the change event of the dropdown and get the selected option value and set to the group_id

```
$(function(){

   $("#groups").change(function(e){
      var v=$(this).val();
      $("#group_id").val(v);
   });    

});
```

I am not sure why you are loading the dropdown content via javascript, but there are other better ways to render a dropdown and pass the selected value back to your controller as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300916/dropdownlist-from-ienumerable/34301135#34301135).

Add a `SelectedGroup` property to your view model

```
public class CreateSomethingViewModel
{
  public int SelectedGroup {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Groups {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action, If you want to load the Groups, you can do it

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateSomethingViewModel();
  //Hard coded for demo. You may replace with your db entries (see below)
  vm.Groups = new List<SelectListItem> {
   new SelectListItem { Value="1","Chase bank" },
   new SelectListItem { Value="2","PNCbank" },
   new SelectListItem { Value="3","BOA" } 
  };
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view

```
@model CreateSomethingViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedGroup,Model.Groups)
  <input type="submi" />
}
```

With this you do not need to use any js code ( Even if you load the dropdown content via javascript), when user changes the dropdown option value, It will be set as the value of the `SelectedGroup` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateSomethingViewModel model)
{
  // check model.SelectedGroup
  // to do : Save and return/redirect 
}
```

Comment: I do it this way bacause I have a parent dropdownlist, and depending on the value chosen in the parent list, the secend dropdownlist is populated in javascript. Is it ok then?

Comment: I thought so. That is fine. You can use the property name as the first param if that is part of your view model as Chris Pratt mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to bind to `group_id` then use that as the name:

```
@Html.DropDownList("group_id", ...)
```

Or, even better, use the strongly-typed helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.group_id, ...)
```