# How to pass edit change in Edit Post MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to call some generic function, to tell me a value of my dropdown list:
[image]
I will hide this oldStatusID.
So, as you can see also in my db:

JobstatusID| Status name
   4       | Prospect/Waiting for proposal

When I change status, for example to "Lost", and click Save, program keeps id=4, instead of id=2..

Here is my view:

```
@using System.Collections.Concurrent
@model DataAccess.PartialClass.StatusPipelineMerge
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>AdeccoView</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PipelineID)

    @*@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StatusID)*@


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectValueMoney, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.ProjectValueMoney, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectValueMoney, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ProjectValueHr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectValueHr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectValueHr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentPipeline, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommentPipeline, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentPipeline, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FCOID, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FCOID, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FCOID, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldStatusId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldStatusId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldStatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientID, "Client Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClientID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Field of Cooperation", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("FCO", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FCOName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Status", new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Status2", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</div>
```

Here is my controller - edit (get&post)

```
  //// GET: AdeccoViews/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        StatusPipelineMerge merge1 = new StatusPipelineMerge();
        merge1.CommentPipeline = db.Pipelines.Find(id).CommentPipeline;
        merge1.ProjectValueHr = db.Pipelines.Find(id).ProjectValueHr;
        merge1.ProjectValueMoney = db.Pipelines.Find(id).ProjectValueMoney;
        merge1.PipelineID = (int)id;
        merge1.JobStatusName = statusOnId(id);
        merge1.FCOID = db.Pipelines.Find(id).FCOID;
        merge1.oldStatusId = statusIDSelected(id);
        // HttpCookie cookie = CookieManager.CreateCookie("MergePipelineStatus", .CreatedBy.ToString(), adeccoView.CreatedTimeStamp.ToString(), id.ToString());
        // Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        if (merge1 == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients.OrderBy(x => x.ClientName), "ClientID", "ClientName", merge1.ClientID);
        //ViewBag.Comment = new SelectList(db.Pipelines, "CommentPipeline", merge1.CommentPipeline);
        ViewBag.Comment = new SelectList(db.Pipelines, "PipelineID", "CommentPipeline", merge1.CommentPipeline);
        ViewBag.ProjectValueHR = new SelectList(db.Pipelines, "PipelineID", "ProjectValueHr", merge1.ProjectValueHr);
        ViewBag.ProjectValueMoney = new SelectList(db.Pipelines, "PipelineID", "ProjectValueMoney", merge1.ProjectValueMoney);
        ViewBag.FCO = new SelectList(db.FCOes, "FCOID", "NameFCO", merge1.FCOName);
        ViewBag.Status2 = new SelectList(getJobStatus(statusOnId(id)), "JobStatusID", "JobStatusName", merge1.JobStatusName);
        ViewBag.Status3 = new SelectList(getJobStatus(statusOnId(id)), "JobStatusId", "JobStatusName", merge1.StatusID);
        ViewBag.OldStatus = new SelectList(getJobStatus(statusOnId(id)), "JobStatusId", "JobStatusId", merge1.OldStatusId);
        return View(merge1);
    }

    //// POST: AdeccoViews/Edit/5
    //// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    //// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Status2,Status3,ID,PipelineID,ProjectValueHr,ProjectValueMoney,CommentPipeline,StatusID,JobStatusName,FCOID,ClientID,CreatedTimeStamp,CreatedBy,ModifiedTimeStamp,ModifiedBy")] StatusPipelineMerge merge)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            string controllerName = "MergePipelineStatus";
            Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline();
            PipelineJobStatu pjs = new PipelineJobStatu();
            pipe.PipelineID = merge.PipelineID;
            pipe.ProjectValueHr = merge.ProjectValueHr;
            pipe.ProjectValueMoney = merge.ProjectValueMoney;
            Employee user1 = Session["User"] as Employee;
            pipe.CreatedBy = user1.EmployeeD;
            pipe.CommentPipeline = merge.CommentPipeline;
            DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            pipe.CreatedTimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlFormattedDate);
            pipe.ClientID = merge.ClientID;
            pipe.FCOID = merge.FCOID;

            pjs.PipelineID = merge.PipelineID;
            pjs.JobStatusID = merge.StatusID;
            pjs.CreatedBy = user1.EmployeeD;
            pjs.CreatedTimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlFormattedDate);
            db.Pipelines.Add(pipe);
            db.PipelineJobStatus.Add(pjs);
            db.Entry(pipe).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(pjs).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            CookieManager.SetCookie(Consts.COOKIE_NAME, 1, "Upešno izmenjen task", EnumNotificationMessageType.success, Response);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.Status2 = new SelectList(getJobStatus(statusOnId(merge.PipelineID)), "JobStatusID", "JobStatusId", merge.JobStatusName);
        ViewBag.Status3 = new SelectList(getJobStatus(statusOnId(merge.PipelineID)), "JobStatusId", "JobStatusId", merge.StatusID);
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName", merge.ClientID);
        //ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeD", "Name", adeccoView.EmployeeID);
        //ViewBag.EventTypeID = new SelectList(db.EventTypes, "EventTypeID", "Event", merge.EventTypeID);
        return View(merge);
    }
```

So, I am tryng for Status2 ViewBag, to pull out id for text/string.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading data for the dropdown ? Try to use a viewmodel with DropDownListFor helper method This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300916/dropdownlist-from-ienumerable/34301135#34301135) might help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried everything the same as on that link, but in the view there as an error: The ViewData item that has the key 'StatusID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'