# MVC5 populating DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have just started developing using the MVC 5 design pattern, I'm trying to populate my `DropDownList` with data from the database, this is what I have in my Country model:

```
public class Country 
{
   public DataTable GetAllCountries()
   {
     string theSql = "SELECT * FROM Country";
     IDataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
     return dataAccess.GetData(theSql);
   }
}
```

Then within my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   List<SelectListItem> objResult = new List<SelectListItem>();
   Models.Country country = new Models.Country();
   DataTable result = country.GetAllCountries();

   foreach(DataRow item in result.Rows)
   {
      SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
      temp.Value = item["id"].ToString();
      temp.Text = item["country"].ToString();
      objResult.Add(temp);
   }
      ViewBag.DropDownResult = objResult;
      return View();
}
```

Then in my Partial view I have:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Country
@Html.DropDownListFor(ViewBag.DropDownResult as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Howvever on `DropDownListFor` I receieve this error:

**No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? If I'm correctly following the MVC pattern also?

Thanks guys

Comment: Add a property to your view model to store the selected item and use it. Working sample code in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300916/dropdownlist-from-ienumerable/34301135#34301135)

Comment: @Shyju I added a property just to test things, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Added a property where ? In your view model ?  As long as you use that new property in your `DropDownListFor` helper method, it should work fine. Take a look at the link i posted in previous comment. It has a working sample.

Comment: @Shyju I understand but from your working example you take a different approach

Comment: Yes. It uses a view model with 2 properties, one for the dropdown data and one for the selected value. Is that a problem ?

Comment: @Shyju I get this error when add the property you say I need. Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedCountry'.

Comment: Without seeing your code, i cannot tell you what is wrong. But looks like you are still using ViewBag. The answer i posted is using a strongly typed view model. Did you even try that ?

Comment: @KTOV, That error means that `DropDownResult` is `null` - probably because you have returned the view in the POST method but have not repopulated the value of `DropDownResult` as you did in the GET method

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in which object is the property you want to display.

`@Html.DropDownListFor` requires atleast 2 parameters. The first should be the object and the second the list which containts the items. 
Something like:

```
 @model MyProject.Models.Country
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, ViewBag.DropDownResult as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: `DropDownListFor()` does not accept a `string` as the first parameter and your code throws an exception- it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, ViewBag.DropDownResult as List<SelectListItem>)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I stated in the answer that it should be an object. Edited to be more precise.